# Retrieving a lookup Value from a List using jquery and REST

Tags: list, jquery, lookup-column, rest

I would like to get the lookup Value from a List item depending on it's Title.

My List is set up similar to the following example:

ColumnA : a | b | c
lookupB : 1 | 1 | 2

The jquery:
`function getValues(ListName)

{`
`$.getJSON('http://<pageName>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/' + ListName + '?',`
`function(data) {`
`$.each(data.d.results,`
`function(index, value) {`
`$('#select').append`
`($('<option>/option>').val(index).html(value.Titel`
`+ value.lookupB));`
`});

});

}`

The #select value is a `<select>` DropDown Menu and the options are filled correctly with the first value, but the lookup value only consists of [Object object] or undefined after trying different keys.

> EDIT: I actually found out by looking into the Array of `value.lookupB` that I can add a `value.lookupB.__deferred`. 
>   The latter returns an uri pointing to:
>   `http://<page>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ColumnA(1)/lookupB`
>   Is there a way to access the information without parsing the JSON again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the solution:

```
function getValues(listName)
{
    $.getJSON('http://<page>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/' + listName,
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,
            function(index, value) {
                i++;
                $('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(index).html(value.ID + " : " + value.Titel));
                getLookup(value.ID, value.Titel);
            });
    });
}


function getLookup(idOfChild, valueOfChild)
{
    $.getJSON('http://<page>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/' + childList + "(" + idOfChild + ")/" + parentList,
        function(data) {
            $.each(data,
            function(index, value) {
                $('#select2').append($('<option></option>').val(index).html(valueOfChild + " : " + value.Titel));
            });
    });
}
```

The first Dropdown is filled with the IDs and value.Titles from the child List and the second Dropdownlist is filled with value.Title of the child : corresponding value.Title parentlist. It works!
The key to the solution was actually as stated in the edit block of my question.

@ErikB: Thank you for your help, helped me bounce quite well.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function getLookupFieldValuesFromListByTitle(listTitle, fieldInternalName, callback) {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext;
  var field = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle).get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldInternalName);
  ctx.load(field);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    // Is not instanceof SP.FieldLookup
    var lookupListId = $(field.get_schemaXml()).attr('List');
    getItemsByListId(lookupListId, callback);
  }, function(a, b) {
    callback(b);
  });
}

function getItemsByListId(listId, callback) {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext;
  var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId).getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
  ctx.load(items);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var e = items.getEnumerator();
    var array = [];
    while (e.moveNext()) {
      array.push(e.get_current());
    }
    callback(null, array);
  }, function(a, b) {
    callback(b);
  });
}
```

It uses ClientContext to get all items from a given list and returns them in an array, so you can loop through them like this:

```
getLookupFieldValuesFromListByTitle('myList', 'myLookupField', function(err, items) {
  $.each(items, function(i, item) {
    $select.append($('<option>').text(item.get_title()).val(item.get_id()));
  });
});
```

Comment: Looking into your answer and doing some reading on javascript object model. Does not work of the bat, sadly even after plugging in the values. Thx for your fast response though.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. You want to get all lookup values for a given field in a list? So you need list title and field title

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I have only used the REST approach so far first time I am looking at the javascript object model. Bit lost to be honest, but trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Updated it to work for lookup, but it became quite horrible. Probably exists another much cleaner way to solve it

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I really am trying to use the REST API will pursue the issue further in that direction. I cannot get your code to run in my solution and am having problems reading into it as I used the foregone mentioned and not the javascript object model.

Comment: Have you looked at the excellent [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) by Marc D?

Comment: I have yes and am using it in other places, but I kind of need a custom solution and am also interested in the technology :P  
I might even have something will post it soon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4797/discussion-between-ben-mcdougall-and-eirikb)