# SharePoint 2010 + Search only within a list

Tags: search, blog

I am using the blog template in SharePoint 2010 and want to provide a Search feature that only returns items within the Posts lists in order to allow users to search through posts based on keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackie,

You can define a new search scope for the site collection.. add the scope to the desired site and use it..

The important points while creating the scope to only search in a specific list is that:

**Scope Rule Type**: Web Address `(http://server/site)`
In Web Address select **Folder** and type the url of custom list e.g. 
`http://server:port/Lists/MyList`

And when the scope is ready, the following rule:

Select **Scope Rule Type** is **Property Query(Author=John Doe)**
In Property Query section, select **contentclass** in Add property restrictions combo box.
In text box type **STS_ListItem_GenericList**

Please have a look at following posts:

[Steps to search a specific custom list](http://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/steps-to-search-a-specific-custom-list/)

[Create a Search Scope for a Sharepoint 2010 List or Library](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST api or CSOM to perform a list search for a client-side solution.
If you know what columns to search for the keyword, take a look at: [Using REST call to retrieve SharePoint list items as an array of JSON objects](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95957/using-rest-call-to-retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-as-an-array-of-json-objects/95960#95960)

For server side: See https://splistfilter.codeplex.com/ can get you started.