# Read variable from sharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

This is my code (Display location on google map)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll like to use a sharepoint List to update my varaibles. Because I don't want end users to get in the code and change location variable. 
I'm using Sharepoint Online.

Thx

---

this is the sharepoint list that I want to manage. 
[image]

Comment: I think an end user would be more likely to modify your variables in a list rather than the code itself.  Regardless, just make the permissions for your users 'Read' on it and it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use Client side coding in javascript with Jquery objects. refer jquery file first in your solution and then call SharePoint List by Title using Javascript on page load( i.e. under document.ready(){} method). Once you have the List you can call each item of the list in form of an array and pass it to your variable.

Couldnt write all the code part but google out you will find lot of sample codes of calling list and items using jquery/javascript.

Comment: hi Antik, Think you for your anwers but still not have a solution.

Comment: check the below two link you will get an idea.. What you are really doing is passing Json objects in a variable which you are referring. Below two links will show you how using REST api to have SharePoint list items in form of JSOn objects:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95957/using-rest-call-to-retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-as-an-array-of-json-objects                         https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api