# code to get title from list and assign to txtbox..but control doesn't reaches ajax block

Tags: jquery, ajax

var qString = null ;
$(document).ready(function () {
try
{
    getDetails();
}
catch(e)
{
    alert("error occured at ready method" + e.message);
}
});

```
if(qString != null)
{

                $.ajax({  
                    url:  _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('My list')/items/?$select=Title&$filter=ID eq "+qString,                   
                    method: "GET",  
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
                    success: function (data)  
                    {  
            onSuccessResult(data);

            },
                error: function (data)  
                {  
                    $('body').html(data);  
                    console.log("error");  
                }  
            });
}


function onSuccessResult(data)
{
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){  
                            var title= (item["title"]); 
                $('#TitleId').val(title); });


  }
```

Comment: Use the code button in the editor to properly format your code, or add 4 leading spaces to every line... Then we might try to read your code.. And might I suggest you try to make it work yourself a bit harder before asking questions. Put a console statement inside the getdetails function and first investigate yourself What might be wrong.

Comment: functn not getting called

Comment: Now retrace your code back... WHY is it not called...Search for ``debugger;`` on Google and learn to debug. Programming is Work with capital W.. just like Sports (with capital S) you have to practice before you can perform

Comment: i m trying to find but cudn't figure this out...so i wud be grateful if u help me out

Comment: when i debug,i find that control reaches to if(qString != null) directly from document.ready without entering into loop and then o/p 1 is coming in console

Comment: That then means q **is** null in the expression; which is logical because your first line is ``q=null`` Hint: maybe you should learn what jQuery s ready function does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qString= null;
$( document ).ready(function() { 
     var qString =  getdetails();

     if(qString != null)
    {
                $.ajax({  
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('My list')/items/?$select=Title,Name,Age,DOB,Indian&$filter=ID eq "+qString,  


                    method: "GET",  
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },  
                    success: function (data)  
                    {  

            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){

                 var title  = item.Title; 
                 var name   = item.Name; 
                 var dob    = item.DOB;  
                 var age    = item.Age;
                 var indian = item.Indian ;
                 var address = item.Address;
                 document.getElementById('AddressId').value = strip(item.Address);
                 document.getElementById('DOBId').value = getDate(item.DOB);
                 $('#TitleId').val(title); 
                 $('#NameId').val(name);
                 $('#AgeId').val(age);
                // $('#DOBId').val(dob);
                 $('#IndianId').val(indian);
                                             });       
            },
                error: function (data)  
                {  

                    $('body').html(data);  
                    console.log("error"); 
                }  
            });
    }
});

function strip(html)
{
   console.log(html);
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   console.log("text" + tmp.textContent);
   console.log("html" + tmp.innerHtml);
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
function getDate(stringDate)
{
  var todayTime = new Date(stringDate);

   return todayTime.toLocaleDateString();
}
function getdetails() 
{
   var result =  window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: how to use " window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1]" in getdetails funcntn to split by id

Comment: Replace var result =  1; line with var result =   window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];

Comment: Mark the answer for helpful to others

Comment: cn u tell me how to get username , lookup field and rich text in the same

Comment: I don't have idea but need to check it.

Comment: how to get lookup field value when lookup internal name is : list_x0020_lookup and fields in list are  list lookup: MyName and list lookup:ID

Comment: Try marked answer in following link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45391/retrieving-a-lookup-value-from-a-list-using-jquery-and-rest